# How much memory is allocated to this Bitmap?

Tags: android, android-bitmap

I'm not quite sure how much memory will be allocated to the following variable "bitmap",

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.example);
bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 100, 100, true);
```

Say, the dimension of the original image is 1024*768 and some memory has been allocated to the bitmap. Then the bitmap was scaled to 100*100, and will the memory allocated to the variable "bitmap" be changed due to the change of the dimension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *variable* only ever takes up a small amount of memory (if any). A few bytes at most. A variable of an object type only uses enough memory to store a pointer to the object.

*Objects* pointed to by variables, however, can take up any amount of memory. [createScaledBitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean)) creates a new bitmap so after your code is run there will likely be two bitmaps in memory. One of them (the original, larger one) however no longer has any live references (e.g. variables) pointing to it, so it will eventually be garbage collected.